# Return All Column Location of String Value (Can be subbed for T/F) in a Row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a quandary - I am attempting to automate a process where I am manually searching across 59 cells per row, looking to provide all cell locations that house the string value of "Unmet" I have a feeling it will be far easier to change the Met/Unmet to T/F values throughout, but I still have the issue of needing to identify all cell locations per row where the value exists. Due to the nature of the data (HIPAA) I cannot share a sample.

There may be one location per row, there may be as many as five. It does not need to be in one cell, I just need to summarize the number of fails/unmet/false per row and where they are (even just the column location will suffice).

I am unable to pivot out the data and provide the file itself, otherwise I would just provide a table of each failure and number of failures per.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only an example *(for 10 columns)*.  Say we have data in cols **A** through **J**.  In the first row, enter the column IDs **A** through **J**.  Then start entering your data starting in row #2.

In **K2** enter the **array formula** and copy downward:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(A2:J2="Unmet",$A$1:$J$1,""))
```

and copy downward.  **Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

[image]

You need to adjust this to match the actual columns *(59 columns)* your data is in.  You can also replace the ID letters in the first row with numbers if you desire.

Comment: Thank you - this would work perfectly if Excel 2013 had TEXTJOIN. I found a VBA another user on stack exchange had provided to mimic the TEXTJOIN function, but it's not working out. I believe this is more than likely the best approach, but I have to find a working VBA to create the add-in for TEXTJOIN. Thank you again.